# Using gRPC for Android Application - Example Application

Tags: android, grpc

i'm trying to include gRPC into my Android Application.
Since I'm really new to all of this, I just tried the example Application given on the gRPC website

https://www.grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/kotlin/quickstart/

But it doesn't work for me.
Running the server works, it is started and listening to 50051. But when starting the application and trying to send a request, the app does shows "UNAVAILABLE" as the servers response.

If there is someone out there, who had and fixed the same issue, please help.

Thanks

PS. It is running on an emulator, but not when i'm using an actual device

Comment: Is the host on which you're running the server accessible to the client on your Android device?

Comment: Is the server running on localhost? The example app by default assumes the server is listening on localhost: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/blob/501df147f948228cb2ead96205567b3e5b487a13/examples/android/build.gradle.kts#L29

Comment: indeed, the server is running on localhost, as described by the example...
sorry for not responding for so long, by the way

Comment: Oh, I might misunderstand your last sentence... So are you saying that it works when running on the emulator but no when on a real device? For running the client on a real device and connect to the server host via USB, you would need to enable reverse port forwarding. In this case: run `adb reverse tcp:50051 tcp:50051`. When your device is trying to access local port 50051, that request will be routed to your laptop's port 50051.